# how to color the rooks in a minimal number of colors in that way – no horizontal and vertical line contains two rooks of the same color?

Tags: algorithm, math, graph, graph-theory

Here is the [problem (Rooks)](http://acm.uva.es/p/v106/10615.html) asks that

> Given a chessboard NxN, on which the rooks are placed. You have to color those rooks in a minimal number of colors in that way – no horizontal and vertical line contains two rooks of the same color.

What type of solution can you offer ?

Thanks

Comment: You should post the complete description of the problem. In the form you gave here it doesn't have sufficient data.

Comment: what do you need extra from this? here is link and here is the description

Comment: It's a good practice on SO to post all the info, not just links.

Comment: I need only an algorithm that is why it is not necessary to write any input for this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Form a bipartite graph with rows as one set and the columns as other.

The rooks would correspond to the edges of the bipartite graph: row r and column c are joined by and edge if there is a rook at position (r,c).

Now you are looking for an edge colouring of this bipartite graph.

It can be shown that (I believe first by Konig) that the minimum number of colours required is same as the max degree and polynomial time algorithms are known (inspite of the general problem being NP-Complete). Thus in your case, the minimum number of colours required will be the maximum numbers of rooks in a row or column.

In fact, the edge colouring corresponds to the vertex colouring of the line graph of a bipartite graph, which is known to be a [perfect graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_graph) and thus the minimum number of colours is the max degree. Polynomial time algorithms to colour perfect graphs are also known, but that would be overkill for this problem.

An algorithm (and references to earlier algorithms) for edge colouring bipartite graphs appears here: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.144.3399&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Answer (score 0):

The lazy approach for *partial points*. Color everything according to this map:

```
1  N  N-1 N-2
2  1  N   N-1
3  2  1   N
4  3  2   1   .  .  .
          .
          .
          .
```

And if after you assign colors to the rooks there are unused numbers left then re-number the coloring.

Comment: This will not give a coluring with the _minimum_ number of colours. For instance, in your example, if we pick the 1 and 4 from column 1 and N and 3 from column 2, you use 4 colours, but 2 are enough.

Comment: @Aryabhatta What part of "lazy approach for partial points" didn't you understand? I knew already this approach doesn't always give the minimum.

Comment: I didn't downvote this, if that is what prompted your irate comment. You didn't mention this in the answer, so I decided to comment to clarify.